# How to delete emails from a string of users?

Tags: vba, outlook

How can I go through this "indefinite 5-10..." list of senders and delete their messages:

***`mySenders =" Dan Wilson, Tom Hanks, Alisa Milano, Jessica Alba, Torrid, Captain America"`***

The code below works for a single sender.

```vb
Sub MoveItems()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myDestFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
    'how to loop here?
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'Kmart'")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Your VBA code here and your question don't match, are you trying to modify to delete messages?

Comment: @Omar, The code as it is deletes any messages from SenderName" Kmart", I need to modify the code to loop through a string containing **multiple senders**. Unfortunately my knowledge ended here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

little confuse. but to delete msg from multiple sender, Add a Second `While .. Wend` and modify it to use [myItem.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343.aspx)

Example:

Tested on  <kbd>**Outlook 2010**</kbd>

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteItems()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items

    '// loop for each sender
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'Dan Wilson'")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Delete
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend

    '// Loop Next Sender
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'Tom Hanks'")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Delete
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend

    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'Alisa Milano'")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Delete
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend

    ' More here
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess this works, somehow I was thinking of something more dynamic: to pull users from the values on the string. I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through an an array based on mySenders.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveItems()

    Dim myNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim myInbox As folder
    Dim myDestFolder As folder
    Dim myItems As Items
    Dim myItem As Object

    Dim mySenders() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set myNameSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myDestFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)

    mySenders = Split("Dan Wilson,Tom Hanks,Alisa Milano,Jessica Alba,Torrid,Captain America", ",")

    For i = LBound(mySenders) To UBound(mySenders)

        Debug.Print i & " - " & mySenders(i)

        Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = """ & mySenders(i) & """")
        While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
            myItem.Move myDestFolder
            Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
        Wend

    Next

End Sub
```

You will need the exact names.

```
Sub display_SenderName()

    Dim currItem As Object

    Select Case ActiveWindow.Class

        Case olExplorer
            ' The active window is a list of messages (folder)
            ' There might be several selected messages
            ' Here only one is processed
            Set currItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
            Debug.Print currItem.Subject
            Debug.Print currItem.senderName

        Case olInspector
            Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
            Debug.Print currItem.Subject
            Debug.Print currItem.senderName

    End Select

End Sub
```